# how to take/parse url of image? JSON / Volley library

Tags: android, json, android-fragments, android-volley, android-json

As you can see in the picture I have **JSON object 'multimedia'** which has information about picture in 4 different formats. I need url only on of them.  Lets say which had standard format (75x75). I use **volley library** in my android application. I am confused about **how to take/parse url (in string format is enough) of image that underlined in the picture**.

[image]

Here is **code** that I used:

NewsFragment:

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        volleySingleton = VolleySingleton.getInstance();
        requestQueue = volleySingleton.getRequestQueue();
        sendJsonRequest();
    }

    private void sendJsonRequest(){
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                getRequestUrl(10),
                null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    parseJSONRequest(response);
                }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
                });
        requestQueue.add(request);
    }

    private void parseJSONRequest(JSONObject response){
        if(response==null || response.length()==0){
            return;
        }
        try {
            JSONArray arrayResult = response.getJSONArray(Keys.EndPointNews.KEY_RESULTS);

            for (int i = 0; i < arrayResult.length(); i++){
                JSONObject currentResult = arrayResult.getJSONObject(i);

                String section = currentResult.getString(Keys.EndPointNews.KEY_SECTION);
                String subsection = currentResult.getString(Keys.EndPointNews.KEY_SUBSECTION);
                String title = currentResult.getString(Keys.EndPointNews.KEY_TITLE);
                String article_abstract = currentResult.getString(Keys.EndPointNews.KEY_ABSTRACT);
                String published_date = currentResult.getString(Keys.EndPointNews.KEY_PUBLISHED_DATE);

                // HERE IS A PROBLEM: EDIT:
                JSONArray arrayMultimedia = currentResult.getJSONArray(Keys.EndPointNews.KEY_MULTIMEDIA);
                JSONObject objectMultimedia = arrayMultimedia.getJSONObject(0);
                String multimediaURL = null;
                if(objectMultimedia.has(Keys.EndPointNews.KEY_MULTIMEDIA_URL))
                {
                       multimediaURL = objectMultimedia.optString(Keys.EndPointNews.KEY_MULTIMEDIA_URL);
                }

                News news = new News();

                news.setSection(section);

                news.setSubsection(subsection);
                news.setArticleTitle(title);
                news.setArticleAbstract(article_abstract);
                Date date = mDateFormat.parse(published_date);
                news.setPublishedDate(date);

                //EDIT
                news.setMultimediaURL(multimediaURL);

                mListNews.add(news);
            }
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),mListNews.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }catch (JSONException e){

        }
        catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

**THANKS FOR ANY HELP!**

EDIT:

```
public String getMultimediaURL(){
     return multimediaURL;
}
public void setMultimediaURL(String multimediaURL){
     this.multimediaURL = multimediaURL;
}
```

Comment: use GSON for parsing your data

Answer (score 2):

I must suggest you to go with GSON library for parsing your JSON reposnses. it is very easy, you have to just create your template/entity classes. here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24514934/1576416)  and download gson library from [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/detail?name=google-gson-2.2.4-release.zip&)

**OR**

refer below answer by @ρяσѕρєя K

**OR**

refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27291512/1576416) answer

Comment: Thanks for information, I just make my first steps and need to study it. =)

Answer (score 1):

`multimedia` is JSONArray instead of JSONObject. get `multimedia` json array from `currentResult` JSONObject:

```
JSONObject currentResult = arrayResult.getJSONObject(i);
JSONArray arrMultimedia = currentResult.getJSONArray(
                                     Keys.EndPointNews.KEY_MULTIMEDIA);
```

`multimedia` array contain JSONObejct so get JSONObject from  `arrMultimedia` to get all values using key:

```
JSONObject jsonObjMultimedia = arrMultimedia.getJSONObject(0);
String strPicUrl=jsonObjMultimedia.optString("url");
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will try to use it as JSONArray but anyway I need only one url of the picture which has format (75x75). What can you advise to me?

Comment: Hello again! Can you check my post again? I updated it with your code but unfortunately there was no result. Whats wrong now?

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek: Use log for `String strPicUrl=jsonObjMultimedia.optString("url");` line and check getting value in logcat or not

Comment: I used Log.i(TAG, "multimediaURL value:" + multimediaURL); and I have value in logcat but why it didnt show it inside the Toast message. I am comfused about it.

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek: try to show only image url like `Toast.makeText(getActivity(),mListNews.get(0).getMultimediaURL().get.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

Comment: ρяσѕρєя K I tried Toast.makeText(getActivity(),mListNews.get(0).getMultimediaURL().toString()‌​,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); but there was no result. Do you think that problems is in set and get methods? I updated post with new code. Can you check it please! God blees you.

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek: comment `Date date = mDateFormat.parse(published_date);
                news.setPublishedDate(date);
` lines then check it also add some text in toast message like `Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"mListNews:"+mListNews.get(0).getMultimediaURL().toString()‌​,To‌​ast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

Comment: I commented that date lines as you said and tested it but no Toast message. But when I tested it without MultimediaURL it works fine. So I dont think that problem is in the date. Somehow it dont want to show url. Its sad =(

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek: What value you have in `Keys.EndPointNews.KEY_MULTIMEDIA_URL` ? are you sure `KEY_MULTIMEDIA_URL="url"` ??

Comment: sure, thats what I used: public static final String KEY_MULTIMEDIA_URL = "url"; and its correct cause in logcat when I tested before as I said I have value of multimediaURL but somehow something wrong with set method news.setMultimediaURL(multimediaURL);  Set and get methods I added to post. Do you have any ideas whats the reason?